# Why I cannot get steps in android wear even use official code provided by google?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, google-fit

I want get steps in android wear and I find a example in github provided by [FitStepsWatchFaceService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/FitStepsWatchFaceService.java)

I also check the **manifest** but still failed.

Please help me,thanks.

Comment: We can't know what's wrong unless you post error messages or a detailed description of what you did, what happened, and what part of that was unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be clear, but you need to enable the Fit API with your project (uses SHA1 from Android app). I used debug one to test the app, you probably want to start with that.

Can you have a look at [this page](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_2_get_a_google_account) for instructions (pretty easy).